Query to find row that has dropped out of a running list
Say I have the below mock data:
CREATE TABLE #table(cobid INT,tradeid VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #table
SELECT cobid, tradeid
FROM (VALUES
    (20240923,'123456'),
    (20240924,'123456'),
    (20240925,'123456'),
    (20240926,'123456'),
    (20240924,'123457'),
    (20240925,'123457'),
    (20240926,'123457'),
    (20240924,'123458'),
    (20240925,'123458'),
    (20240923,'123459'),
    (20240924,'123459')
) t(cobid, tradeid)

I need a query that flags any tradeid that begins to appear in the list and then drops out. For example I want to flag 123458 as missing for 20240926 but I don't care that it wasn't present for 20240923.
I have seen elsewhere recommended using CROSS JOIN on the cobid to create a full combination, but I can't get it to work.
To clarify - it should not flag a tradeid for any dates before it first appears. I want to flag missing tradeids in the running date list after they first appear

I finally made the below work, but is there a cleaner way?
Cleaner = I really feel this is not too complicated an ask in a database language, but I'm struggling to find a way that isn't  convoluted.
--build cartesian product of all possible tradeids and cobids
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT cobid 
        FROM #table
    ) x
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT tradeid 
        FROM #table
    ) y
), 
ctf AS (
    SELECT c.tradeid tradeidmaster,
        c.cobid cobidmaster,
        t.cobid,
        t.tradeid,
--mark each row as a valid instance or not, summing along the way
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.tradeid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
        OVER (PARTITION BY c.tradeid ORDER BY c.cobid) checkval
    FROM cte c 
    LEFT JOIN #table t ON t.cobid = c.cobid AND c.tradeid = t.tradeid
)
SELECT *
FROM ctf
--filter out all rows before tradeid first existed
WHERE ctf.checkval <> 0
--flag any others that are missing 
AND ctf.tradeid IS null


Please add FULL expected output, not just 1 record that should exist in the output, so anyone can know what your (total)expected  should look like.  BTW: "cleaner way" is opinionated!

@Luuk The query in the question already returns the right results (3 rows), based on the wording in the question as I've read it.

i want to flag 123458 as missing for 20240926m but I don't care that it wasn't present for 20240923. Can you explain this a little better? Why does 0923 not matter?

I suspect that once a tradeid appears the expectation is that there will be daily entries therafter from the first appearance to 'todays' date and the drop out date is the earliest date after the last daily entry that the tradeid does not appear.

Hi have clarified the original post. What i'm finding is this problem is a bit of a long walk for a short drink of water, unless i'm missing something

The first thing to do is fix the schema (because it really is broken) so the date values are actually stored in a date column.

@JoelCoehoorn how would that help in any way?
And not really broken just yyyymmdd, valid across our system

Storing the value as numbers instead of dates means you have to cast the values first in order to use date functions, and from there tends to break indexing and force per-row conversions on every row in a table, even when only a few are needed. If your SQL database has a Date type you should use it.

If i understand the question correctly, perhaps something like:
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    SELECT  max(cobid) OVER() AS maxDate
    ,   max(cobid) OVER(partition BY tradeid) AS maxDatePerTrade
    ,   *
    FROM    #table
    ) x
WHERE   x.maxDate > x.maxDatePerTrade

I fetch max trade date over the whole group and compare it with the max date per trade. This won't detect holes, but you didn't mention that.
Output:



maxDate
maxDatePerTrade
cobid
tradeid




20240926
20240925
20240924
123458


20240926
20240925
20240925
123458


20240926
20240924
20240923
123459


20240926
20240924
20240924
123459



It's easy to group this further if you're only interested by the IDs
